# How do I auto-update an array in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I am trying to add an item to the end of an array, kind of like an arraylist. I tried using the .push() but I can't get it working correctly reading from my xml. How could I "auto" update the array in jquery? (append to the end of it if you want to think of it that way)

Here is what my jquery looks like at the moment.

```
images = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: strXMLURL,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("image").each(function() {
                    images.push($(this).attr("src"));
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error reading the XML"); 
            }
        });
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gallery>
    <image src="images/gallery/gallery1.jpg"/>
</gallery>
```

If you need any more information, I'll happily provide more.

Comment: if you console.log($(this)) does it actually show the XML node that you think you have? If you have a choice, there's often less friction in your web service responds with JSON, because it's already in a format of a javascript object, so is easy to work with (I think)

Comment: Well I am getting the correct data, I just need to keep adding it to an array.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/9682/  I would make sure your "images" variable is actually scoped properly and not being cleared/modified in other places, and debug through the success function.

Comment: I think that may be the problem, is the scope

here is the code

`var images = new Array();
  images = loadGalleryImages();` loadGalleryImages() returns an array.

Comment: If you post more of your code, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the images array inside the success function of the ajax call to ensure the scope remains correct then your function should work...